# MST_Kruskal algorithm C++

Tags: c++, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, minimum-spanning-tree, kruskals-algorithm

I find the algorithm below, but I didn't understand how that works and what edges class must contain. Please if anyone can understand it tell me a description:

```
void MST_Kruskal(edges edge[], map<string, double>& nodeSet, set<edges>& eSet, int n)
{
    quick_sort(edge, 0, n - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        
        if (nodeSet[edge[i].getAuthor(false)] != nodeSet[edge[i].getAuthor(true)])
        {
            eSet.insert(edge[i]);
            double s1 = nodeSet[edge[i].getAuthor(true)];
            double s2 = nodeSet[edge[i].getAuthor(false)];
            for (map<string, double>::iterator it = nodeSet.begin(); it != nodeSet.end(); it++)
            {
                if (it->second == s1)
                    it->second = s2;
            }

        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm

Comment: Strange to use pointer (edge) instead of `std::vector`/`std::span` (whereas `std::set`/`std::map` are used).

Comment: i understand the global algorithm but i didn't understand this code. mostly, with that edge[i].getAuthor(false)], edge[i].getAuthor(true)] this getter should return double just by changing the bool in the parameter of the getter it's logical?

Comment: check this one https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kruskals-minimum-spanning-tree-algorithm-greedy-algo-2/